# Async Await on MVC Controller with repository that selects and returns a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, async-await, iqueryable

I have an MVC controller action that lists all of the "features" I have for a given "application" and then displays it as a table.

**Am I using async correctly here?**

The controller action is async i.e.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string id)
{
  return View(await new FeatureRepository(_context).GetAllFeatures());
}
```

and my features repository (I'll instantiate via dependency injection later)...

```
public class FeatureRepository
{
  private ApplicationDbContext _context;

  public FeatureRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  public async Task<IQueryable<ApplicationFeature>> GetAllFeatures()
  {
    var query = from d in _context.ApplicationFeatures
                select d;

    return query;
   }

}
```

Or do I need to use:

```
await query.ToListAsync()
```

Then return a List?  Trying to avoid ToList of any kind as I don't want to run the query until it is required i.e. defer the execution.

It seems to run fine but before I reproduce this X times, I wanted to be sure it has been done in a way that does not still behave synchronously.

Thanks!
Dan.

(MVC 6, ASP.NET 5, Entity Framework 7, VS2015)

Comment: What model is the view expecting? A `List<ApplicationFeature>`?

Comment: IEnumerable<T> is the standard collection type (@model IEnumerable<ApplicationViewModel>) when outputting a collection to a view but I'm really after an async pattern that will allow me to refine my query once returned from the repository in case I want to perform further filtering on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your await GetAllFeatures isn't awaiting nothing as the method isn't performing any async operation, just returning an IQueryable.

So you need to call ToListAsync somewhere. If you want your repo to return the queryable then remove all async/await from there and use the ToListAsync in the action.

By the way, remember naming async methods with Async suffix as suggested by Microsoft by convention.

Just for clarifying when EF exposes async and when not (because doesn't have any sense):

The point of async actions in MVC is to free IIS threads when there are operations not requiring IIS processing. The most common and clear case is DB operations.
That's why mostly all MVC async examples are related to EF, because the you can leave IIS attend other requests meanwhile DB is processing queries.

That being said, and talking about EF, only EF methods that expose async are those that perform database operations. That's why you don't have "AddAsync" (because Add works only with DbContext) and you do have "SaveChangesAsync" (because it actually executes db insert in this case).

Conclusion: to take full advantage of async actions, you should use all EF async methods you have available. If your action doesn't consume any async method, then the action shouldn't be async.

Comment: It's being called within an async method - does this mean it is not async or just that the query is not async?  I want to refine query further once retrieved from repository i.e. deferred execution - ToListAsync makes the call the database there and then and stores the collection in the query variable.  I'm trying to pass back something that might be IQueryable for further tweaking before executing against the database.  I don't understand why I can't just return back an IQueryable/IEnumerable in as async manner.  There's async for everything else so I'm confused.  What is the best practice?

Comment: Your repo method only build the query, doesn't perform anything else. So asynchronism there has no sense. Async helps when there is a task that will take time to avoid blocking your app thread while (in this case) db is working. You'll find methods in dbcontext and dbset that allow you to use await, as ToListAsync, SaveChangesAsync, etc, all methods that exec db commands, not just building the query. As per defer excecution, it's ok to execute query in action, after that you only have view rendering (actually I avoid letting actions manipulate queries but it's another discussion)

Comment: I have an async controller action in MVC.  How do I call a non-async method in the repository class?

Comment: Sorry didn't understand the question.. is it a new one? or about the same?

Comment: Same mostly,  I am trying to figure out how I supposed to use async and await with MVC.  Some of my methods in the repository (called from the async controller action) will be async, some won't be.  Can I leave my controllers to be all async, and call non-async methods in my repository.  Or once I've chosen to use an async controller does everthing that it calls then need to be async also?  Is the await mandatory? By not using await does it mean it's just a non-synchronous method?

Comment: You can call non-async methods anywere. But it's supposed if you choose to go async then implement async methods for db access. I'll add some text to the answer trying to explain some basics I think you didn't get

Comment: Cool - you've been a great help.  I think I understand.  So all my controller actions can continue to be async.  I can have a IQueryable non-async method on my repository and use async for the database interactions (select, insert, update, delete).  Then when I finalise my use of IQueryable, i can then use await when I come to execute it.  All my MVC controller actions can continue to be async because they can call non-async methods and even though I am awaiting nothing - that's ok coz it still works.